# Send and receive email by Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

We have build custom crm app(rails 4.0).  One of the features that we have build is that we send emails to our customers based on booking status or we send a custom email by our travel agents.

The next thing we want is that customers can replt on this email.  So we can recognize the email thats replyed and related to the initial email is send, so we have a nice email dialog (send/receive) in the crm.

Someone ideas how we can "recognize" the replyed email so we can related it to the right email?

Thanks..remco

Comment: Have you tried griddler: https://github.com/thoughtbot/griddler ?

Answer (score 2):

In your email client open a reply from someone and show full headers or raw source (how to get it depends on the client but you will find it!)

When you look at the email headers you will find `References` field

```
References: <CAAC3oDjZSFywS5mpAANO+svm-3xXwLciUhw_QEkBkNqT9A@mail.com>
            <06AFEF94-53D2-4469-59B0A494830C@mail.de>
            <E67E3945-D61E-8E45-63C52D111698@mail.net>
```

And more importantly

```
In-Reply-To: <6397034C-90CA-41B4-F47AE3F39E76@mail.de>
```

While every outgoing email has a `Message-ID` field

```
Message-ID: <569F22.8060202@mail.de>
```

To get an if of you outgoing message

```
result = SomeMailer.message(params).deliver
result.header['Message-ID'].value
```

Comment: thanks..don't really understand you're answer. We send a email from our crm with sender: support@support.com. The the customer replyes on this email. How can we recognize the replyed email so we can related it to the initial email ? So we can build a email dialog

Comment: When you send the initial email from CRM you should get and save the message-id I mentioned. This way when I customer replies you can find the original message-id in their response in the header field `In-Reply-To`. Sorry if the ID's don't make sense, I had to scramble them a little!

Comment: @Remco Please let me know if you end up using this solution! :)

Comment: discussing with our main developer. I let you know!